# sed - trying to replace first occurrence after a match

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, sed

I am facing a situation that drives me nuts.
I am setting up an update server which uses a json file.
Don't ask why or how, it sucks and is my only possibility to achieve it.

I have been trying and researching for HOURS (many) because I went ballistic and wanted to crack this on my own. But I have to realize I got stuck and need help.

So sorry for this chunk but I think it is somewhat important to see...

The file is a one liner and repeating the following sequence with changing values (of course).

`"plugin_name_foo_bar": {"buildDate": "bla", "dependencies": [{"name": "bla", "optional": true, "version": "1.00"}], "developers": [{"developerId": "bla", "email": "bla@gmail.com", "name": "Bla bla2nd"}], "excerpt": "some text {excerpt} !bla.png|thumbnail,border=1! ", "gav": "bla", "labels": ["report", "scm-related"], "name": "plugin_name_foo_bar", "previousTimestamp": "bla", "previousVersion": "1.0", "releaseTimestamp": "bla", "requiredCore": "1", "scm": "github.com", "sha1": "ynnBM2jWo25ZLDdP3ybBOnV/Pio=", "title": "bla", "url": "http://bla.org", "version": "1.0", "wiki": "https://bla.org"}, "Exclusion": {"buildDate": "bla", "dependencies": [],`

and the next plugin block is glued straight afterwards.
What I now want to do is to search for `"plugin_foo_bar": {"` as this is the unique identifier for a new plugin description block. 
I want to replace the first sha1 value occuring afterwards. That's where I keep failing. I always grab the first,last or any occurrence in the entire file and not the block :(
`"title"` is the unique identifier after the sha1 value.

So I tried to make the .* less greedy but it ain't working out.

last attempt was heading towards:
`sed -i 's/("name": "plugin_name_foo_bar.*sha1": ")([a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%^&*()\[\]]*)(", "title"\)/\1blablabla\2/1'` default.json

to find the sha1 value of that plugin but still no joy. I hope someone knows - preferably a simpler approach - before I now continue with trial and error until I have to puke and freakout.

I am working with SED on Windows, so Unix approach might help me to figure out how to achieve this in batch but please make it as one-liner if possible. Scripts are a real pain to convert.

And I just need SED and no other solution with other tools like AWK. That is absolutely out of discussion.

Any help is appreciated :)

Cheers
Jan

Comment: First, the section of json you give seems incomplete, or at least it doesn't appear to be balanced.  Is there some missing text?  Second, in the main text you say you want to search for '"plugin_foo_bar" : { ... }".  Is this a typo for '"plugin_name_foo_bar"'?  The sed example you give looks instead for the '"name" : "plugin_name_foo_bar"', which is somewhat different, although both are before the '"sha1"' field.  Which one were you trying to say?

Comment: I know you have to have a sed solution, but unless this a sed assignment, I would strongly suggest looking at `jq` (http://stedolan.github.io/jq/).  jq is a very powerful command-line json manipulator (a bit like awk if awk had been designed to read/write json natively).  There are windows 32- and 64-bit binaries available.  The simplest jq solution looks roughly like `   jq -c '.plugin_name_foo_bar.sha1 = "xyzzy"'`

Comment: The snippet is indeed not complete but the part of interest is that particular piece here. It is re-occuring several hundred times.

There is in fact a typo. sorry for that :(
"name": "bla" should have been "name": "plugin_name_foo_bar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As sputnick points out parsing is a little beyond what sed's meant for.  Still, sed's Turing-complete and bludgeoning it into doing what you want can satisfy that {sad,masoch}istic urge so many of us feel from time to time.

This one's even easy.

```
sed '
   s/"sha1": /\n/g
   s/\("name": "plugin_name_foo_bar"[^\n]*\n"\)[^"]*/\1thenewsha/
   s/\n/"sha1": /g
'
```

Comment: Thanks mate :)
your solution did for some reason not work for me but you did provide me a new PoV how to solve this.
Simply break the file into more managable chunks.

`for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%i in ('type latest.txt') do (
 sed -i 's/\(%%i.*sha1":"\).*\("},\)/\1%%j\2/1' default.json
)`

Did then what I actually was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex (sed) to parse JSON, instead use a proper JSON parser, or javascript directly like I do :

Using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) in a script :

File `/tmp/file.json` is :

```
{
   "plugin_name_foo_bar" : {
      "excerpt" : "some text {excerpt} !bla.png|thumbnail,border=1! ",
      "dependencies" : [
         {
            "name" : "bla",
            "version" : "1.00",
            "optional" : true
         }
      ],
      "title" : "bla",
      "previousTimestamp" : "bla",
      "releaseTimestamp" : "bla",
      "sha1" : "ynnBM2jWo25ZLDdP3ybBOnV/Pio=",
      "labels" : [
         "report",
         "scm-related"
      ],
      "buildDate" : "bla",
      "version" : "1.0",
      "previousVersion" : "1.0",
      "name" : "plugin_name_foo_bar",
      "scm" : "github.com",
      "url" : "http://bla.org",
      "gav" : "bla",
      "developers" : [
         {
            "email" : "bla@gmail.com",
            "developerId" : "bla",
            "name" : "Bla bla2nd"
         }
      ],
      "wiki" : "https://bla.org",
      "requiredCore" : "1"
   },
   "Exclusion" : {
      "dependencies" : [],
      "buildDate" : "bla"
   }
}
```

The script `script.js` :

```
var js = require('/tmp/file.json')

js.plugin_name_foo_bar.sha1 = "xxx"
console.log(js)
```

Usage :

```
nodejs script.js
```

Comment: The idea is tempting but I am working in a very strict environment :/

Answer (score 0):

For windows command line, with escaped quotes, replacing inline and using regular expression

```
sed -i -r "s/(plugin_name_foo_bar.+?sha1\": \")[^\"]+\"/\1abcdefghijkl\"/" default.json
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r "s/(plugin_name_foo_bar[^!]+sha1.: .)[^\"]+/\1abcdefghijkl/" file
```